# Is the Google Chrome for 32bit Mac

Tags: google-chrome, 32-bit

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8. I downloaded Google Chrome but in my Applications Chrome has a cross. When I open it, it says my Mac is not compatible.

Once I booted with 64bit and Chrome was working! **However my Internet (dial-up) does not work in 64bit (32 only).**

---

Is there a way to get Chrome on 32 bit for Mac? I downloaded Chrome official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google discontinued its 32-bit version for OS X almost a year ago.  Additionally even if you could get a 32-bit version it is going to have lots of security issues. So why would you want to run it knowing it has lots of unresolved security issues!

From [Install Chrome on your computer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en):

> Mac
>
> System requirements
>
> To use Google Chrome, your computer needs:
>
> - Mac OS X 10.6 or later
> - An Intel processor that's 64-bit
> - 350MB of free disk space
> - 512MB of RAM

Also have a look at the following two hyperlinks.  The first of which I added an image of in case the link goes dead in the future.

- [Google to Discontinue 32-bit Chrome for Mac Next Month](http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-32-bit-mac-discontinued-later-year/)
- [Chrome for OS X turns 64-bit, forsakes early Intel Macs](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2849225/chrome-for-os-x-turns-64-bit-forsakes-early-intel-macs.html)

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will stick with safari for now then.